# Find sequence algorithm for a list of expressions?

Tags: sympy

Is it possible to use sympy to find the algorithm for a sequence of expressions?

For example, if I have the following list:

```
s = [ fraction(1/1), fraction(1/2), fraction(1/4), ... ]
```

Can sympy extract the expression representing this list of expressions?

```
>> fraction(1/(2**(x-1)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described, this is not a well-defined task. The formula `1/(1+x*(x-1)/2)` also fits the given data. More generally, for any finite set of data points there are infinitely many formulas that match all points exactly; which one should be returned as the answer?

SymPy does have interpolation routines `interpolate` and `rational_interpolate`; the former returns a polynomial and the latter a rational function passing through the given points. ([Reference](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polyfuncs.interpolate).) Polynomial interpolation can be used in your example **if** you know that an exponential function should fit, and therefore take the logarithm of data, as follows:

```
s = [Rational(1, 1), Rational(1, 2), Rational(1, 4)]
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
result = exp(interpolate([log(y) for y in s], x)).simplify()
print(result)
```

This prints `2**(-x + 1)`. The idea is that taking logarithm turns exponential function into linear, which can be constructed with `interpolate`.

But generally speaking, the problems of fitting a curve of some form to given data are solved numerically with packages like scikit-learn.